# Network doesn't assign IP, need to type some commands to make it work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ip

I have a problem with my laptop, because everytime I want to connect to any local network via Ethernet cable or Wifi, then it doesn't assign any Ipv4, so that there is no possibility to have an internet connection.
I need to plug reconnect to the internet + use the command below:

```
dhclient -i wlp3s0 -4
```

where wlp3s0 is the name of my interface. After shooting it couple of times, it works normally untill I restart my computer.
OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't use any VPN connection.

cat /etc/network/interfaces  output:

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Post output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @NasirRiley , I have updated my post

Comment: Your interface of `wlp3s0` is not in the file and hence won't receive anything via DHCP or at all. Add your interface next to `auto` and `iface` with the others and then reboot and you should get an address for it. You need to do that with any interfaces you want to receive addresses via DHCP.

Comment: @NasirRiley ,
After adding, there is no network connection via ethernet as well as none wifi networks are found.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make your `/etc/network/interfaces` look like this

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface wlp3s0 inet dhcp
```

The additional line tells the traditional networking scripts to automatically start `dhclient` for the `wlps3s0`. Note the top line is a comment and should already start with `#`; if not, your current file is broken.

If you are running network manager, this may or may not work; I can't help you with network manager.

Comment: After adding, there is no network connection via ethernet as well as none wifi networks are found.

Comment: So the next step is to find out if you are running [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager), and if yes, try to find out what goes wrong with it.

Comment: Yes. I am using NM but I have no idea what's more I am able to do with it